# How to set the name of the next Future thread in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency

When new thread is created with the use of the `scala.concurrent.Future` trait, new Thread's name is generated automatically.

```scala
import java.lang.Thread
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

Future { 
  println(Thread.currentThread().getName()) 
}

// Result is: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29
```

How can I set the name of the next Thread created by the Future trait?

---

Note: this can be useful especially when logging the name of the Thread, so that you have better idea of what's going on (which thread is doing what).

E.g. my log4j configuration is `%d{yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %p: %m%n`. The `%t` shows the Thread name. While letting Scala decide the name is seamless, I'd rather choose the Thread name by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this done via custom `ThreadFactory`, which creates new `Thread` with the desired name.

All you have to do, is to specify the desired name before you declare new `Future` object, like follows:

```scala
import java.lang.Thread
import scala.concurrent.Future

// Import the custom implementation, which is elaborated below
import cz.jkozlovsky.scala.utils.Concurrent._

nextFutureThreadName("FuturesEverywhere")

Future {
  println(Thread.currentThread().getName()) 
}

// Result is: FuturesEverywhere
```

Here is the definition of my `Concurrent` object:

```scala
package cz.jkozlovsky.scala.utils

import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutorService, Executors, ThreadFactory}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, ExecutionContextExecutor}

/** Custom concurrency object to enable custom thread names.
  */
object Concurrent {

  protected var desiredThreadName: Option[String] = None

  protected val globalThreadFactory: ThreadFactory = {
    runnable: Runnable =>
      if (desiredThreadName.isDefined) {

        val name = desiredThreadName.get
        desiredThreadName = None

        new Thread(runnable, name)
      } else {
        new Thread(runnable)
      }
  }

  protected val globalThreadPool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
    10,
    globalThreadFactory
  )

  /** Sets the name of the next thread created by the [[scala.concurrent.Future]] trait.
    */
  def nextFutureThreadName(name: String): Unit = desiredThreadName = Some(name)

  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(globalThreadPool)
}
```